# Applying pnorm to columns of a data frame

Tags: r, loops, apply

I'm trying to normalize some data which I have in a data frame. I want to take each value and run it through the pnorm function along with the mean and standard deviation of the column the value lives in. Using loops, here's how I would write out what I want to do:

```
#example data
hist_data <- data.frame( matrix( rnorm( 200,mean=5,sd=.5 ),nrow=20 ) )

n <- dim( hist_data )[2] #columns=10
k <- dim( hist_data )[1] #rows   =20

#set up the data frame which we will populate with a loop
normalized <- data.frame( matrix( nrow = nrow( hist_data ), ncol = ncol( hist_data ) ) )

#hot loop in loop action
for ( i in 1:n ){
   for ( j in 1:k ){
      normalized[j,i] <- pnorm( hist_data[j,i], 
                                mean = mean( hist_data[,i] ), 
                                sd = sd( hist_data[,i] ) )
   }  
}
normalized
```

It seems that in R there should be a handy dandy vector way of doing this. I thought I was smart so tried using the apply function:

```
#trouble ahead
hist_data <- data.frame( matrix( rnorm( 200, mean = 5,sd = .5 ), nrow=10 ) )
normalized <- apply( hist_data, 2, pnorm, mean = mean( hist_data ), sd = sd( hist_data ) )
normalized
```

Much to my chagrin, that does NOT produce what I expected. The upper left and bottom right elements of the output are correct, but that's it. So how can I de-loopify my life?

Bonus points if you can tell me what my second code block is actually doing. Kind of a mystery to me still. :)

Comment: In your example code, the words rows and columns are reversed in the comments. Also,  you define the variables n and k to hold columns and rows, then fail to use them in the matrix command. Might want to clean that up so others aren't confused.

Comment: good point on the wording being backward. But as for n and k, they are used in "for (i in 1:n)" and "for (j in 1:k)"

Comment: Right. Missed that second part. Good post!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want:

```
normalize <- apply(hist_data, 2, function(x) pnorm(x, mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))
```

The problem is that you're passing in the individual column into `pnorm`, but the entire `hist_data` into both the mean & the sd.

As I mentioned on twitter, I'm no stats guy so I can't answer anything about what you're actually trying to do :)